I'm working on Twitter Clone project and I'm trying to keep Thumbs up like icon visible I got it to toggle on and off properly
I'm able to toggle on and off Thumbs up icon to like and unlike messages but thumbs up icon won't stay visible.
@app.route('/messages/<int:message_id>/like', methods=['POST'])
def add_like(message_id):
    """Toggle a liked message for the currently-logged-in user."""
    if not g.user:
        flash("Access unauthorized.", "danger")
        return redirect("/")

    liked_message = Message.query.get_or_404(message_id)
    if liked_message.user_id == g.user.id:
        # Retrieve liked messages IDs from the session or initialize if not present
        liked_messages_ids = session.get('liked_messages_ids', [])

        if message_id in liked_messages_ids:
            liked_messages_ids.remove(message_id)
        else:
            liked_messages_ids.append(message_id)

        # Store liked messages IDs back into the session
        session['liked_messages_ids'] = liked_messages_ids

        db.session.commit()
    
    return redirect("/")

I've tried adding EventListener to likes.html file but still doing the samething. I was hoping this would allow Thumbs Up icon to remain visible.
